# Can I use a S3 endpoint for Amazon Athena?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I would like to know if it is possible to configure an endpoint to S3 (S3 endpoint) for AWS Athena, not the VPC endpoint. I have looked at it everywhere in the documentation I could not find it. Is this even possible?

The idea is to use the endpoint to get to S3 for all the Athena queries.

Thanks and best regards
Krishna

Comment: This might help. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/analyze-logs-athena/?nc1=h_ls

Comment: Do you mean - if AWS athena can access S3 through an S3 private link?

Comment: Yes, like 
aws --endpoint-url https://example.com s3 @gusto2

Comment: Why do you wish to use `--endpoint-url` with Amazon Athena? Are you wanting it to access data stored in an S3-compatible service?

Comment: Yes, @JohnRotenstein. I really appreciate your prompt support, Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `--endpoint-url` is normally used to override how the AWS CLI access an AWS service.

I see it used when people use an S3-compatible service such as [Wasabi](https://wasabi-support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001910791-How-do-I-use-AWS-CLI-with-Wasabi-), where they are pointing to a different service rather than the 'real' S3.

Amazon Athena knows how to connect directly to Amazon S3. It is not possible to override the S3 Endpoint when Athena connects to S3.

Comment: thank you so much @johnrotenstein, greatly appreciate your prompt help.